# Javascript: How to include a url in a string variable?

Tags: javascript, string

new to this javascript thing. This is driving me crazy!

How do I add a URL in a string variable?

This is what I have:

```
function getRiskMessage(){

    var msg = " visit our advice website at <a href=\'http://www.example.com\'>this site</a>";

    if(totalRiskScore > 25){
        //this message (High Risk)

        msg2  = show();


    }//close if

    return msg;

}
```

but when i output it to a div instead of a link 'this link' - I get the a tag and url as string like above.

What am I doing wrong, need to understand this.

Comment: *"when i output it to a div"* - show how you do it.

Comment: Where is the `show()` function.  You're assigning the `msg` variable from the return value of the `show()` function and then returning that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*tl;dr You're using `createTextNode`, which creates a plain-text node. Don't do that :) Use the `innerHTML` property instead. See below for more details.*

---

You don't need to escape quotes unless they resemble the start and end quotes:

```
var foo = "Visit <a href='http://bing.com'>Bing</a>.";
```

In the above, the string begins and ends with double-quotes, so single-quotes can be used without any problems.

```
var foo = "Visit <a href=\"http://bing.com\">Bing</a>.";
```

In the above, we use double-quotes around the string, and around the [href] attribute. As a result, the inner-quotes (around the attribute) must be escaped so they don't confuse the parser.

Lastly, when you output, make sure to output as HTML:

```
div.textContent = foo; // Represents foo as plain text
div.innerHTML = foo; // Interprets foo as HTML
div.appendChild( document.createTextNode( foo ) ); // Similar to textContent
div.appendChild( document.createElement( "span" ) ).innerHTML = foo; // HTML
```

#### Example:

```js
document.querySelector( ".msg" ).innerHTML = "Visit <a href='http://bing.com'>Bing</a>.";
```

```html
<div class="msg"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thy this:

```
var msg = document.createElement('span');
msg.innerHTML = " visit our advice website at <a href=\'http://www.example.com\'>this site</a>"
container.appendChild(msg);
```

Working demo: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dgrk9fex/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example on how to insert html using plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById('your-div').innerHTML = msg
```

Here is a fiddle of your case: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cbk2d5ad/)